# Regular expression to split ruby strings into multiple hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, postgresql

I have a string like this one in a jsonb column in my Postgresql database:

```
"{\"monday\"=>\"{:start_time=>9.0, :end_time=>10.5}\"},{\"tuesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"},{\"wednesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"}"
```

Now I want to use regular expression to make it look like this one:

```
[{\"monday\"=>\"{:start_time=>9.0, :end_time=>10.5}\"}, 
{\"tuesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"},
{\"wednesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"}
]
```

I am trying to use the method split with regular expression to accomplish the task. However, I still couldn't figure it out how to split only the commas that are right after the closing curly braces in the string. 
All I can think of is testing it with the scan method in ruby like this:

```
test =  "{\"monday\"=>\"{:start_time=>9.0, :end_time=>10.5}\"},{\"tuesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"},{\"wednesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"}"
result = test.scan(/\"},/)
=> result = ["\"},", "\"},"]
```

It seems like I am going on the right track, but I am stuck here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update**
Thank you Mr. Tinman for your thoughtful explaination. I changed the database back to hstore, and use JSON.stringify before passing my data to the backend side.  With some twisting here and there, I can finally get the hash I want as you suggested:

```
{"monday"=>{"start_time"=>9, "end_time"=>10.5}, "tuesday"=>{"start_time"=>8.5, "end_time"=>10}, "wednesday"=>{"start_time"=>8.5, "end_time"=>10}}
```

. However, after saving it to the database, all the values of the hash are serialized as string:

```
{
       "monday" => "{\"start_time\"=>9, \"end_time\"=>10.5}",
      "tuesday" => "{\"start_time\"=>7, \"end_time\"=>8.5}",
    "wednesday" => "{\"start_time\"=>7, \"end_time\"=>8.5}"
}
```

I know I can convert them back to hashes by using eval. However, are there any ways for me save those values as hashes also in the database or I can't because of Hstore mechanism?

Comment: I am not sure, but have you tried JSON.parse?

Comment: @gates `=>` is not valid JSON, so it would fail to be parsed as is.

Comment: Why do you have Ruby code in a jsonb column?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: The reason is I want to extract the keys and values of each separate hash in the string.

Comment: It looks like you've stored the string version of the elements of an array of hashes, instead of doing the right thing and storing the individual values in a separate table, or serializing the data using JSON, and are now painted into a corner. See "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you tried to create your own JSON serializer, instead of using the one that comes with Ruby. Or, perhaps you didn't realize that JSON was a thing and wanted to store arrays of hashes and tried to invent your own. Either way, it wasn't a good path to follow.

This is your definition, which, after being retrieved would remain a String. It appears to be the elements of an Array of Hashes, without the surrounding Array `[` and `]`:

```
foo = "{\"monday\"=>\"{:start_time=>9.0, :end_time=>10.5}\"},{\"tuesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"},{\"wednesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"}"
```

and it remains a String:

```
foo.class # => String
```

It'd be possible to munge it back into a form that could be evaluated and turned back into an Array of Hashes, but it's not straightforward, nor is it clean or convenient or elegant.

I suspect your original object looked like this:

```
foo = {"monday"=>{:start_time=>9.0, :end_time=>10.5}},{"tuesday"=>{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}},{"wednesday"=>{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}}
# => [{"monday"=>{:start_time=>9.0, :end_time=>10.5}},
#     {"tuesday"=>{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}},
#     {"wednesday"=>{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}}]
```

which is an Array:

```
foo.class # => Array
```

It's an Array now because you have multiple Hash elements separated by commas (`,`) which Ruby interprets as an Array when assigned to a single variable. This would be a less visually confusing example:

```
foo = {a: 1}, {a: 2} # => [{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}]
foo.class  # => Array
foo.first.class # => Hash
```

Back to the Array of Hashes in `foo`: Starting from that it's easy to let the JSON class serialize it into a string that can be stored in a database, then retrieved and reparsed back into a Ruby object:

```
require 'json'
foo.to_json
```

`foo.to_json` would result in a serialized string that looks like:

```
[{"monday":{"start_time":9.0,"end_time":10.5}},{"tuesday":{"start_time":8.5,"end_time":10.0}},{"wednesday":{"start_time":8.5,"end_time":10.0}}]
```

And, given that string, JSON can rebuild the object:

```
bar = JSON.parse(foo.to_json)
# => [{"monday"=>{"start_time"=>9.0, "end_time"=>10.5}},
#     {"tuesday"=>{"start_time"=>8.5, "end_time"=>10.0}},
#     {"wednesday"=>{"start_time"=>8.5, "end_time"=>10.0}}]
```

Note that it's not necessary to use `parse` or `to_json`. The class is smart enough to recognize whether the parameter is a String, or an Array or Hash, and parse or serialize respectively:

```
JSON[JSON[foo]]
# => [{"monday"=>{"start_time"=>9.0, "end_time"=>10.5}},
#     {"tuesday"=>{"start_time"=>8.5, "end_time"=>10.0}},
#     {"wednesday"=>{"start_time"=>8.5, "end_time"=>10.0}}]
```

At this point you're prepared to store the values into a String-type field in your database, then retrieve them later and reuse them.

If you are hoping to search or manipulate those stored JSON strings, I'd recommend re-thinking that. While a modern DBM can search inside JSON and generate it, you'd be better off having a separate table of the keys and values. It's faster and more flexible.

Finally to your question, how to convert the string so you can get the keys and values:

```
foo = "{\"monday\"=>\"{:start_time=>9.0, :end_time=>10.5}\"},{\"tuesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"},{\"wednesday\"=>\"{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}\"}"
bar = eval('[' + foo.gsub(/"([{}])/, '\1') + ']')
bar
# => [{"monday"=>{:start_time=>9.0, :end_time=>10.5}},
#     {"tuesday"=>{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}},
#     {"wednesday"=>{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}}]

bar.map { |h| [h.keys, h.values.first.keys] }
# => [[["monday"], [:start_time, :end_time]],
#     [["tuesday"], [:start_time, :end_time]],
#     [["wednesday"], [:start_time, :end_time]]]
```

This hints that the Array of Hashes wasn't the right structure either. A simple hash would have sufficed:

```
foo = {
  "monday"=>{:start_time=>9.0, :end_time=>10.5},
  "tuesday"=>{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0},
  "wednesday"=>{:start_time=>8.5, :end_time=>10.0}
}

require 'json'
bar = JSON[JSON[foo]] # imitate a round-trip to/from the DB
bar.keys # => ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday"]
bar.values # => [{"start_time"=>9.0, "end_time"=>10.5}, {"start_time"=>8.5, "end_time"=>10.0}, {"start_time"=>8.5, "end_time"=>10.0}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've just updated my question. Please take quick look when you have time.